# Display TIFF_JPEG Compression image on a picture box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tiff, image-compression, libtiff.net

Is it possible to display a Tiff image with TIFF_JPEG compression on a picture box using Windows forms?

I have used LibTiff.Net to change compression but this increase the size of the image a lot .. since i need the tiff image loaded using System.Drawing.Image to display it, I would like to know if it is possible to display it directly instead of doing the conversion to a bmp or JPG.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **System.Drawing.Image.FromFile** method to load tiff image and set it to picturebox.Image

pictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"filepath");

Comment: Well, that would work with a regular tiff image (Group 4) but if i use  it with a tiff with TIFF_JPEG compression will raise a "Out of memory" exception, or if I try to use MemoryStream will raise a "Invalid Parameter".